# Appending to the same array with foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop a foreach array and add new values to the same array but it's not returning the values;

```
<?php
    foreach($departments as $department){
        $department['users'] = 10;
    }
?>
```

but when I return the array, 'users' won't be a part of the list. I tried array_push, with not much luck either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php):

```
foreach($departments as &$department){
  $department['users'] = 10;
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to drop (unset) the reference after the loop.. ;)

Comment: Just curious, is there some subtle reason for doing that?

Comment: In case you need to use the same variable (`$department`) later it will still reference that last item in the array unless explicitly unset.

Comment: Yes, but that's obvious. I thought there was some micro-optimization thing behind your reasoning :)

Comment: Nope. Considering this reference concept is new to OP I thought I should mention that.